# Continuous gradient over multiple shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In adobe illustrator, I have multiple shapes that I want to share a single gradient with.
Right now, when I apply a gradient fill each shape handles it's own gradient.

Is there a way to make all the shapes share one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close! With all shapes selected use the gradient tool (G key) to click and drag the in a desired direction to modify the gradient of all shapes.